# find name of all classes with their namespace

Tags: c#

how can i find all classes in my assembly which their name space start with MyProject and ends with Attribute
for example:

```
MyProject.Model.Attribute or MyProject.Personnel.Jobs.Attribute?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with Linq:

```
var myClasses = GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
                   .Where(t => t.Namespace.StartsWith("MyProject") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Attribute"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

     foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
     {
        if (type.Namespace.StartsWith("MyProject") && type.Namespace.EndsWith("Attribute"))
        {
           Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved using LINQ and reflection.

```
var desiredTypes =
                myAssembly.GetTypes().Where(
                    item => item.Namespace.StartsWith("MyProject") && item.Namespace.EndsWith("Attribute"));
```